# Move Code causes broken Import

Tags: vb.net

I move a .vb module from one folder to another and now an Import cannot find it.

In Default.aspx.vb I have an Import that looks like this:

```
Imports XYZ
```

I moved the code from:

```
App_Code\XYZ.vb
```

to:

```
Utils\XYZ.vb
```

I moved it because I now understand that `App_Code` is some kind of special folder and I did not want this code treated as special code.

I tried adding

```
Namespace Utils
End Namespace
```

in `Utils\XYZ.vb` and changing to `Imports Utils.XYZ` but the import still did not resolve.

In case it matters I am using VS2017.

[EDIT]  It appears that the problem is that VS2017 can't see the code moved as I can build and publish without error.

Comment: Try deleting the (hidden) .vs folder in the root folder for your solution.  Visual Studio caches some design-time build information there, and isn't always good about refreshing it.  There have been several bugfixes related to that in the maintenance releases.